# Facing ModuleNotFoundError while executing unit testcase in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have project structure as below.

```
gwpl_data_processing
   |
   |==src
   |     |
   |     |==domains
   |     |   |
   |     |   |==account
   |     |        |
   |     |        |==account.py
   |     |==utils
   |           |==utils.py
   |
   |==tests
         |
         |==test_account.py
```

I have imported utils package in **account.py** as below

```
from utils.utils import schema_validator
```

At above line inside account.py am facing below **error**.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module utils
```

FYI. Getting this error only when i execute unit test case from **gwpl_data_processing** folder as below.

```
gwpl_data_processing>python -m unittest tests.test_account.py
```

FYI. I am able to execute above command successfully. If, i specify complete module path account.py

```
For. E.g 
from src.utils.utils import schema_validator
```

But I do not want src to be a part of import statement. How can i execute unit test successfully without including src.

Please suggest me your solution on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi guys , I found solution for this problem. I had to add only one line of code in test_account.py file. sys.path.add('./src').

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem. I had to add only one line of code in test_account.py file as below.

sys.path.add('./src').